# Can't update repos due to a malformed sources.list file. How can I fix it?

Tags: updates, repositories

Unfortunately (and quite stupidly), I had .txt files set to open with Libreoffice Writer by default, and when I clicked on my sources.list file to add something, it opened up there.  I suspect this is likely the cause of my problem, as now I can't get my repos to update, or install any packages.

When I try to update the repos, I get the following error message:

```
E: Type '﻿deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Line 1 in sources.list reads:

```
deb cdrom:[elementary OS 5.1 hera - stable amd64 (20200814)]/ bionic contrib main non-free
```

Commenting out the first line doesn't help either.  If I put a "#" before "deb" I get the following error message:

```
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (type)
```

Given that I can't install any packages or update my repo until I fix this, what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following command to fix your `sources.list` (copy and past):

```
cat <<EOF |sudo tee  /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ bionic partner
EOF

sudo apt update
```